# Not able to get Apache2.2.17 to load PHP5.3.5 on WindowsXP Please Help!

Tags: php, apache

I installed Apache2.2.17 and then installed PHP5.3.5 and Apache will start but it willn't read any of the PHP.  For instance the code below will not show me the phpInfo() file?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello in PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello in PHP</h1>

<? print "Hello, world!"; 
   phpInfo();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have added the following lines of code to httpd.conf file and installed php as a module.  I used the VC6 x86 thread safe microsoft installer

```
#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/PHP/"
#ScriptAlias /php/  "C:/Program Files/PHP/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
#AddModule mod_php5.c
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
```

Any comments would help I have been trying for two days to get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/apache/php-5.3.4/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/apache/php-5.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Apache 2.2.17 & Php 5.3.4 and have the following lines at the bottom of my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/apache/php-5.3.4/php5apache2_2.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/apache/php-5.3.4"
```

Note: is there a php.ini in PHPiniDir? IT isn't there by default.

And it is:

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Above configuration works fine!